# how to extract data from html table using jQuery each function

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I'm need to extract data from a html table to create a JSON array.

Here is the structure of HTML table,

```
    <table class="tableClass">
        <thead class="tableHeaderClass" >
           <tr>
              <th>header_column1</th>
              <th>header_column2</th>
              <th>header_column3</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tableBodyClass">
           <tr>
              <td>row1_column1</td>
              <td>row1_column2</td>
              <td>row1_column3</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>row2_column1</td>
             <td>row2_column2</td>
             <td>row2_column3</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

In my JavaScript function, I'm doing this

```
  function() {

    var json = {
        header_column1 : '',
        header_column2 : '',
        header_column3 : ''
    };

    var data = [];
    $('tableClass').find('tbody').children('tr').each(function() {
         var $tds = $(this).find('td');
         json.header_column1 = $tds.eq(0).text();
         json.header_column2 = $tds.eq(1).text();
         json.header_column3 = $tds.eq(2).text();

         data.push(json);
    });

    return data;

 }
```

when I print my array, but I'm getting only 'row2_column1, row2_column2, row2_column3'.

Couldn't workout what I'm doing wrong/missing. Would be great if you could help me out with this.

Comment: There's no way you could get anything at all as long you use `$('tableClass')` without `.`

Comment: You can also condense the each line to: `$('.tableClass tbody tr').` no need to do a find and then children call

Comment: Also your code makes no sense at all, you have headers and non-headers elements but you fill your Object literal with properties named "header_column1" ... you should be clear about your code logic before trying anything. Also using `=` instead of `:` are errors that easily catchable by just opening *Console* or using a better text editor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I've just started to get my teeth into JS, still fairly inexperienced I guess..really welcome your feedback it helps me to improve the quality of my code..oh btw, there are some typos as well..forgotten the . and used = instead of : will correct my post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector, `$('tableClass')` will try to select an element with a name of tableClass, ie: `<tableClass></tableClass>`
You can use this instead:

```
$('.tableClass tbody tr')
```

Also since you are using an object each element in the array is going to reference the same object

```
//Clones the json object, might not be the most efficient method 
var newHeader = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json));
//Or just create a new object each iteration
var newHeader = {};
newHeader.header_column1 = $tds.eq(0).text();
newHeader.header_column2 = $tds.eq(1).text();
newHeader.header_column3 = $tds.eq(2).text();

data.push(newHeader);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) about object cloning.

Comment: Thanks Patrick!!, creating a new object each iteration did the trick!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tableClass')
```

Should be

```
$('.tableClass')
```

When debugging jQuery, **always** make your selectors the initial suspects. Check they're finding elements before continuing the chain. Thus:

```
alert($('tableClass').length)
```

...would give you `0`.

(Sidenote:

```
$('tableClass').find('tbody').children('tr')
```

can be shortened to

```
$('tableClass').find('> tbody > tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the selectors, the object syntax is invalid, it should be:

```
var json = {
    header_column1: '',
    header_column2: '',
    header_column3:''
}
```

Also, you are updating and pushing the same object twice, so you will end up with two references to the last update on your array. In essence just getting 'row2_column1, row2_column2, row2_column3' twice on the array, instead of 'row1_column1, row1_column2, row1_column3' and 'row2_column1, row2_column2, row2_column3'

Ditch the var json declaration on top and just do this within the 'each':

```
var json = {}
json.header_column1 = $tds.eq(0).text();
json.header_column2 = $tds.eq(1).text();
json.header_column3 = $tds.eq(2).text();
```